# Read modbus address using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, uart, fread, modbus

I have a robot with multiple modbus motors slaves. I have created a script to check all the modbus addresses to figure out the addresses of the modbus slaves.
So some addreses will return an answer (7 bits) and some others will not return anything.

To retrieve the data I'm using `fread`. The problem is that when I check an address with no slaves, MATLAB throws this warning (and error) and got stuck.

```
b=[];
for i = 1:1:7
a = fread(s,1,'uchar'); 
b = [b decimalToBinaryVector(a,8)];
end
disp(b)
```

> Warning: The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period.
> 'serial' unable to read any data. For more information on possible reasons, >see Serial Read Warnings.

Is there any way to bypass that warning/error? I would like to bypass that so that the script can continue checking the rest of the addresses.

Comment: Which version of Matlab do you have?  2019b added `serialport` which is very helpful for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [`try, catch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) statement. Basically it tries to run a piece of code and when execution fails (i.e. MATLAB throws an error) tries an alternative. You can just leave the alternative blank and it'll skip the errored line:

```matlab
b=[];
for i = 1:1:7
    try
        a = fread(s,1,'uchar'); 
    catch
    end
    b = [b decimalToBinaryVector(a,8)];
end
disp(b)
end
```